# Magento 2 Search Bar error

Tags: magento2, error, search, custom-extension

We are using Magento 2.3.2 and integrated Smile/Elasticsuite for faster search. If we type  a search keyword we  get suggestions and if we  click on the  suggestion we see the result, however, if we type a search keyword and press enter or click on the search icon, we  get below error

> {"0":"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'search_result.score' in 'field list', query was: SELECT 1 AS
>   `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`,
>   `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`comparison_table`,
>   `e`.`size`, `e`.`size_value`, `e`.`documentation`, `e`.`spec`,
>   `e`.`name`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`,
>   `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`image`,
>   `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`news_from_date`,
>   `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`image_label`,
>   `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`price_type`,
>   `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`msrp`,
>   `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`url_key`,
>   `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_exist`,
>   `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`swatch_image`, `e`.`brands`,
>   `e`.`brands_value`, `e`.`descatalogado`,
>   `e`.`custom_stock_status_qty_based`, `e`.`askforprice_textbox`,
>   `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
>   LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
>   price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`,
>   `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`,
>   `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,
>   search_result.score AS `am_relevance` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS
>   `e`\n INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
>   price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
>   AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0\n INNER JOIN
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id
>   = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE (e.entity_id IN (46477, 45678, 46514, 48479, 51841, 54904, 44105, 45535, 49124, 57386, 42755, 42870,
>   44183, 48555, 49800, 54201, 54204, 54207, 54903, 54905, 55075, 55331,
>   58060, 58633, 43243, 44114, 46527, 46821, 48546, 51826, 51854, 59843))
>   ORDER BY `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` DESC,
>   `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` DESC,
>   `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` DESC\n LIMIT 32","1":"#1
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(array())
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php:303]\n#2
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:480]\n#3
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT 1 AS `sta...', array()) called
>   at
>   [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Adapter\/Pdo\/Abstract.php:238]\n#4
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT 1 AS`sta...', array())
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:542]\n#5
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT 1 AS
>   `sta...', array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:617]\n#6
>   Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(&Magento\Framework\DB\Select#00000000181c6d34000000000a18c82b#,
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:737]\n#7
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(&Magento\Framework\DB\Select#00000000181c6d34000000000a18c82b#,
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/Db/FetchStrategy/Query.php:21]\n#8
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query->fetchAll(&Magento\Framework\DB\Select#00000000181c6d34000000000a18c82b#,
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php:778]\n#9
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_fetchAll(&Magento\Framework\DB\Select#00000000181c6d34000000000a18c82b#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:1130]\n#10
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_loadEntities(false,
>   false) called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:927]\n#11
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->load(false,
>   false) called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:803]\n#12
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->load(false,
>   false) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#13
>   Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->___callParent('load',
>   array(false, false)) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#14
>   Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#15
>   Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load',
>   array(), array(array('add_stock_inform...'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteCatalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Fulltext/Collection/Interceptor.php:39]\n#16
>   Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor->load()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-review/Observer/CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver.php:42]\n#17
>   Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver->execute(&Magento\Framework\Event\Observer#00000000181c68fc000000000a18c82b#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n#18
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(&Magento\Review\Observer\CatalogBlockProductCollectionBeforeToHtmlObserver#00000000181c68fd000000000a18c82b#,
>   &Magento\Framework\Event\Observer#00000000181c68fc000000000a18c82b#)
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n#19
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance'
>   => 'Magento\Review\O...', 'shared' => false, 'name' => 'review'), &Magento\Framework\Event\Observer#00000000181c68fc000000000a18c82b#)
>   called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:66]\n#20
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_block_pr...',
>   array('collection' =>
>   &Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor#00000000181c6d37000000000a18c82b#))
>   called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95]\n#21
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_block_pr...',
>   array('collection' =>
>   &Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor#00000000181c6d37000000000a18c82b#))
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:482]\n#22
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:116]\n#23
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->_getProductCollection()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct.php:357]\n#24
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getIdentities() called
>   at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]\n#25
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callParent('getIdentities',
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#26
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
>   called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#27
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getIdentities',
>   array(), array(array('Amasty_Sorting::...'))) called at
>   [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/ListProduct/Interceptor.php:39]\n#28
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct\Interceptor->getIdentities()
>   called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Layout/Layo
>   "1049410248972" [noeol] 1L, 16523C

Can someone please help with it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you change the search engine to Elasticsearch from backend?

Comment: Yes I did , its running on Elasticsuite

Comment: As far as i can see its not creating a temporary table id suggest you report it to the extension creator and raise an issue on github

Comment: so is it elasticsuite which is creating issue? or someother plugin ?

Comment: The issue was becasue of Amasty extension. I have disabled it and it worked. Thank you very much for the pointers.